# Using a gsub to insert a word rather than replace a word

Tags: r, gsub

I have the following file path to which i want to rename. The current path (for an example) is `Downloads/strip/2022.dat` and i wish to change this to `Downloads/strip/old/2022.dat`. I've tried gsubbing like this;

```
aa = Downloads/strip/2022.dat
aa = gsub("\\/strip/.+", "/Old/", aa)
```

where im trying to say keep everything with the ,+ and add "old after the strip/ but this still seems to remove the strip/. I've also tried `.^` and `.$` but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, we can try the following approach with `sub()`:

```r
x <- "Downloads/strip/2022.dat"
output <- sub("([^/]+)$", "old/\\1", x)
output

[1] "Downloads/strip/old/2022.dat"
```

Comment: What if the file path is something like this: `"Downloads/strip/ANOTHEREXTRA/2022.dat"`? Or is `strip` ALWAYS the last alphabetic string?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann My interpretation of the requirement is that the name of the final path parameter is not relevant.  Rather, the requirement is to add a _new_ path `/old` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it more simply by replacing 'strip', with 'strip/old'. No regex required:

```
aa ='Downloads/strip/2022.dat' 
gsub("strip", "strip/old", aa, fixed = TRUE)
[1] "Downloads/strip/old/2022.dat"
```

Comment: You're right that it's unnecessary to use regex here - and better to avoid regex when unnecessary - but you forgot to add `fixed=TRUE` to actually not use it!

Comment: Thats a good point :)

Comment: A literal pattern is still a (regex) pattern

Comment: Note that this approach assumes that the final path parameter is `strip`.